# Destructuring objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code base I have an object:

```
let myObject = {
  "version": 1,
  "traceId": "123456789",
  "session": {},
  "trigger": {
    "service": "some_service_is_here",
    "action": "update",
    "resource": "transaction"
  },
  "changesets": [
    {
      "update": {
        "retryCount": 1
      },
      "conditions": {
        "equal": {
          "subscriptionId": "aaaaaaaaaaaa",
          "transactionId": "bbbbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "update": {
        "retryCount": 2
      },
      "conditions": {
        "equal": {
          "subscriptionId": "ccccccccccccc",
          "transactionId": "dddddddddddddd"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract some properties from that object. So far it is done using Lodash. There are more extractions going on, but they are fairly identical. Several examples of using it with Lodash:

```
const trigger = _.get(myObject, 'trigger', null);
const retryCount = _.get(myObject, 'changesets[0].update.retryCount', null);
```

It works and behaves as expected. I would like to improve this code, by eliminating Lodash and start using Destructuring.

So far I have this:

```
const trigger = _.get(myObject, 'trigger', null);

becomes

const {trigger} = myObject;
```

And also:

```
const retryCount = _.get(myObject, 'changesets[0].update.retryCount', null);
```

becomes

```
const {changesets: [{update:{retryCount:retryCount = null}}]} = myObject;
```

It also works, test are passing:

Now I have several questions:

1. Is this the correct practice to extract those values?
2. Is it worth it, in terms of speed and code readability?
3. The second destructuring example. I will receive an changeset array, that has many objects (unknown number), but I am always interested in the first one. The lodash example illustrates that. When I destructure, I do not specify that I need a first one (zero based) it comes in by default. Do I need somehow to specify I need the zeroth one, or it is default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but currently your variants are not equal. You need to specify `null` to be default value in variant with destructuring .
2. Code is not faster. As for readability - it depends.
3. You currently specify index explicitly by items' position in the list. So for example

   ```
   const {changesets: [,,{update}]} = myObject;
   ```

   would explicitly extract 3rd element. You don't need to do anything extra.

PS `retryCount:retryCount` better don't specify the same name twice. it looks confusing. Reader(like me) will re-read for several times trying to figure out the difference.

Comment: If I omit retryCount. So [{update:{retryCount:retryCount = null}}] becomes [{update:{retryCount = null}}]... then it seems that retryCount is always null. However with name duplication like retryCount:retryCount, then the values is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nope, in case of destructuring `=` means not assigning but providing default value.  You can easy check it with simpler code right in your browser's console: `var {a = null} = {a: 25}` leads variable `a` to equal 25.

Comment: I am on Node environment. This is strange. After I do  [{update:{retryCount = null}}]. Then I do console.log(retryCount) for example six times... it prints ZERO six times (zero is coming in). Then I hit breakpoint. Then I hover the cursor where I provided retryCount = null, I hover on retryCount... then retryCount becomes instantly null.

Comment: Might be hard to explain, but this is really strange. Using WebStorm.

Comment: maybe webstorm's issue. or nodejs's. I have not experienced such a case when actual value differs from inspected one.

Comment: A side note. Logic dictates that lodash can't be faster. This test supports it: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/501/10/es6-destructuring-vs-lodash-get. Additionaly, when I set console.time() and console.timeEnd() it shows speeds up to 40% faster for native destructuring.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I completely agree that custom function is by default slower than native version. But also I'm sure this will never be a performance issue in real-world project.